# AngularJS: ng-show element visible while the condition is not met

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="AppController">
    boxWidth: {{boxWidth}}
    <div ng-show="activeWindow1" style="border:1px solid black; width: {{boxWidth}}px; height:20px;">
    </div>
    <div ng-show="activeWindow2" style="border:1px solid red; width: {{boxWidth}}px; height:20px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function AppController($scope) {
    $scope.getWidth = function() {
        return $(window).width();
    };
    $scope.$watch($scope.getWidth, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.boxWidth = newValue / 10;
        $scope.activeWindow2 = true;
    });
    window.onresize = function(){
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fQgXQ/20/

Note that activeWindow1 is never set to true, so technically we should never see the black box, right? Try resizing the window, resulting in the $scope.apply(); call and see what happens.

Result: Both boxes are visible (recent Chrome browser).

There is an easy workaround, which is to take the ng-show out into a new div, making the current one its child. However, I'd like to understand why this is happening as it certainly seems like an Angular bug. I suspect I'm just doing something I'm not supposed to with the {{boxWidth}} inside style="". If so, what's a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the style attribute (from both boxes) is being recalculated after each `$apply` (because Angular has to interpolate the value from `{{boxWidth}}`), which will automatically remove the `display: none` property (responsible for hiding the element) set by the `ng-show` directive.

To avoid this, use the `ng-style` directive, like this:

```
<div ng-show="activeWindow1" style="border:1px solid black; height:20px;" ng-style="{width: boxWidth}">
```

Comment: It appears that in some cases, you need to add 'px' to the value, such as: $scope.boxWidth = 300 + 'px', although it seems to work fine without the 'px' in my simplified example above. I haven't looked into why this is, but hope that helps :)